# ruby on rails parsing variable to function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone tell me difference between theese two code examples? What changes when putting ":" at the end of variable name?

```
def initialize(email:)
  @email = email
end
```

```
def initialize(email)
 @email = email
end
```

Comment: It is a named parameter and is extremely helpful when someone else is reading/updating your code. Since Ruby is loosely typed, it can be hard for large teams to work on a Ruby project together. I believe Rubucop's standard rule set requires named parameters when there are five or more params passed to a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`email:` in the method definition argument means that the method will be expecting a key-value pair as the method arguments.
Sample initialization call:

```
YourClass.new(email: email_param)
```

while a simple `email` in the method definition argument means that the method will assign the passed argument to the variable `email`.
Sample initialization call:

```
YourClass.new(email_param)
```

Answer (score 0):

`email:` is [keyword argument](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments)

Keyword arguments follow any positional arguments and are separated by commas like positional arguments

It work this way:

```
def my_method(arg1:, arg2: "default", arg3:)
  puts "arg1: #{arg1}, arg2: #{arg2}, arg3: #{arg3}"
end

my_method(arg3: 3, arg1: 1)
# will print arg1: 1, arg2: default, arg3: 3

my_method(arg2: 2, arg1: 1, arg3: 3)
# will print arg1: 1, arg2: 2, arg3: 3

my_method(arg2: 2)
# will raise ArgumentError (missing keywords: arg1, arg3)
```

Arguments order is important if these arguments are not keyword

```
def my_method(arg1, arg2 = "default", arg3)
  puts "arg1: #{arg1}, arg2: #{arg2}, arg3: #{arg3}"
end

my_method(1, 3)
# will print arg1: 1, arg2: default, arg3: 3

my_method(1, 2, 3)
# will print arg1: 1, arg2: 2, arg3: 3

my_method(1)
# will raise ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3))
```